# middleware in mongoose vs replica set for things like sending emails/sms

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Which one is better approach for things this sending *Emails ,Sms (for account verification) , notifications bla bla* via `nodejs` application

As per my knowledge there can be two approaches.

1. **Execute a function after save which will do this... one can use mongoose middleware like after save..**
2. **Simulate triggers with the help of replica set in mongodb** and run it through background jobs

I think second approach is better because it will be executed by some other process in background, But on the other hand `node.js` is **asynchronous** may be `node.js` handles these kind of stuffs in a smart way .. any idea !!!

**In short**: Sending Sms emails notification after user regestration should be send by `nodjs` middleware or by background process
and as per my knowledge background process can be executed by binding a listener to `oplog`

Comment: Replica set has nothing related to the questions. You want to run an action after save, do it directly in node. If you want to do it in another process, build another application (#microservice) and simply request the new app through HTTP when you have mail/sms/notifications to send.

Comment: @Dafuck "Replication" may not have a "direct" relation, but the "side effect" of even  a "single member replica set" is actually that there is an ["oplog"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) kept which is essentially every write action, so you could "monitor" that and "trigger". I believe the OP was aware of this by the way they phrase their question, but you however do not seem to be aware of this. Many things ( notably meteor ) use this as the method for change notifications, etc.

Comment: Was it not clear in the comment that the question here is way "too broad" if not entirely opinion based. Writing a "how to" for trailing notifications in the oplog is way outside the scope of answers for Stack Overflow, and any response would not come near explaining the necessary process. So it's not clear what sort of answer you are expecting from what can reasonably be given.

Comment: @neil Lunn : I want to keep sms sending or email sending outside the req/res loop... Is background jobs  a better approach to minimise overall req/res  timing, or should I use mongoose middleware to do this , I have a doubt when a client will get response that he is successfully created (1) just after insert query (2) OR just after sending email verification in node js

Answer (score 2):

The best approach for triggering an sms/email service request after saving the document in mongoDB would be through some messaging queue.

I would recommend using **[RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)**. It will segregate the process of sending sms/email from your req/res loop. Invoke it after the success of save function and it will get added in the queue with a completely different process. You can simply return the success result of save function without waiting for the response of message worker.

The messaging queue comes with many more features like delivery acknowledgement, scalability options, apis and guis for managing and monitoring the status of actions performed.

You can either set it up on the same server or deploy on a separate server according to the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

As of MongoDB 3.6, you can do exactly this via [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/changeStreams/). They are a new feature API that let you trigger all sorts of actions based on events happening in the database.